# Data Frame Join

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, join, jupyter

I'm using Jupyter notebooks to join two data frames together and I'm getting the following error. Does anyone know the right way to write this?

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

`data_set = git_author.join(repo_team, on=git_author.project==repo_team.gitProject)`

Answer (score 0):

You error `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects` comes from the fact there is not a column with the same label in both data frames that you can use with a key. Then, I suggest using:

```
data_set = git_author.merge(repo_team, right_on = "project", left_on = "gitProject")
```

Additionally, you can specify the `how` parameter to tell merge whether you want to do an inner join, outer join, left join or right join.

This way, you can specify the label of the column to be used as a key on the merge, even though that label is different for both data frames.

NB: since I don't have your data, it has not been tested.

Comment: thank you for the recommendation - when I add that leverage that statement it gives me the following error:
```NameError: name 'project' is not defined```

I tried adding the prefix for each data frame so the join would look like this: 
```data_set = git_author.join(repo_team, right_on = git_author.project, left_on = repo_team.gitProject)```
and i get this error - TypeError: join() got an unexpected keyword argument 'right_on'

Comment: @rmeyer You may need to format them as String, I edited the answer (my oversight there)

Comment: thank you, but that just took me to this error: 


ValueError: len(left_on) must equal the number of levels in the index of "right"

Comment: @rmeyer: another idea: use merge instead of join. I also edited the answer, hopefully it will do it this time...